# Measuring energy immediately after measuring spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

If you have a system of two particles and you measure $S_{z,(1)}$ and get $\hbar/2$ and $S_{z,(2)}$ to be $-\hbar/2$. And you look at the possible states of the system and found that this one is the only one with the quantum numbers $1/2$ and $-1/2$.

$\left| \alpha\right> =\left| s=1 m_s=0 \right>= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left| m_1=\frac{1}{2},m_2=-\frac{1}{2}\right> + \left|m_1=-\frac{1}{2}, m_2=\frac{1}{2} \right> \right)$.

If we then do a measurement of the energy immediately after. Are we sure only that we are in the state $\left|\alpha\right>$, so we have 50/50 probability for each of the states in $\left| \alpha\right>$, or are we now sure that the system has collapsed into the state
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left| m_1=\frac{1}{2},m_2=-\frac{1}{2}\right>$?

Particle one is located at site 1 and particle two is located at site 2.
$\hat{H}=-c\ \vec{S_1}\cdot\vec{S_2} $, where c>0 is some constant.

Comment: Are the two particles distinguishable or not ? Also, is the energy just $S_{(1)}^2 + S_{(2)}^2$ or is there some external magnetic field or coupling between the spins ?

Comment: They are located at two spesific sites. I don't know if that would make them distinguishable. There is no magnetic field. The Hamiltonian is on the form $\hat{H}=-c \vec{S_1}\cdot\vec{S_2} $, where c>0 is some constant.

Comment: The localization at specific sites makes the particles distinguishable (see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/296989/solublefish) for example).

Answer (score 0):

After measuring $S_{z,(1)}$  at $\hbar /2 $ and $S_{z,(2)}$ at $-\hbar /2 $, the system is already in the state :
$$|\psi\rangle = |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle$$
(with a different, more concise notation for the spin states).
The eigenstates of $H = -c \vec S_1 \cdot \vec S_2$ are $|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle,|\downarrow\downarrow\rangle, \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle + |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle), \frac1{\sqrt 2}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle-|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle)$.

If we then measure the energy, we get  :

- with a 1/2 probability, an energy $ -c\hbar^2/4$ and the system in the state $|\alpha\rangle =\frac1{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle + |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle)$.
- with a 1/2 probability, an energy $3c\hbar^2 / 4$ and the system in the state $|\beta\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt 2}(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle-|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle)$.